# Why is ElevatedButton getting stretched and becoming a background?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new on flutter and I don't have an idea why ElevatedButton stretched and become a background. I just want a simple button. How can I solve this problem? Here's the image below:

[image]

Here's my code

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Image.asset(
                          'profile_image.jpg', height: 150, width: 150,),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        Text("Hello World"),
                        const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                        const Text('Go back'),
                      ],
                    )
                 )
              ),
           ),
        )
     );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using button on `body`. that's why full body acting as button.

```dart
   body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
```

What you seek is just wrapping the `Text('Go back')),` with `ElevatedButton`.

```dart
 return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'profile_image.jpg',
            height: 150,
            width: 150,
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Text("Hello World"),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: const Text('Go back')),
        ],
      ))),
    ));
```